# Удаление курсива при выделении жирным

Tags: jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста: при нажатии на кнопку "Заменить курсив полужирным начертанием" курсив после выделения жирным должен удаляться. Сейчас курсив жирным выделяется, но остаётся.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $("#children").click(function() {
    var $a = $(".one").children()
    alert($a.text());
  });
  $("#contents").click(function() {
    var $a = $(".one").contents()
    alert($a.text());
  });

  $("#jQ").click(function() {
    $('i').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
      })
      .wrap('<strong></strong>')
  });
  $("i").replaceWith($("i"));
}
```

```css
#ctnr div {
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 140px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctnr">
  <div class='one'>
    Текстовый узел 1
    <p>Текстовый узел 2</p>
    Текстовый узел 3
  </div>
  <input type="button" id='children' value="Метод children()">
  <input type="button" id='contents' value="Метод contents()">
  <p class='jQ'>
    <i>jQuеry</i> — библиотека <i>JаvаSсript</i>, фокусирующаяся на взаимодействии
    <i>JаvаSсript</i> и <i>HTML</i>. Библиотека <i>jQuеry</i> помогает легко получать доступ к любому элементу <i>DОM</i>, обращаться к атрибутам и содержимому элементов
    <i>DОM</i>, манипулировать ими. Также библиотека <i>jQuеry</i> предоставляет удобный АPI по работе с <i>АJАX</i>.
  </p>
  <input type="button" id='jQ' value="Заменить курсив полужирным начертанием">
</div>
```

Comment: Отформатируйте пожалуйста ваш код.

Comment: А зачем вы добавили в вопрос определение jQuery из Википедии? Думаю, что те кто смотрят этот вопрос, знают что такое jQuery

Comment: Отредактировала  - заменила код изображением. Html отображался некорректно даже после выбора режима html-вставки в вопросе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот так например:

```js
$("#bt").on("click", function() {
  $("i").replaceWith(function(){
    return $("<strong>", {html: $(this).html()});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i>Этот шрифт курсив </i>
<br>

<i>И еще </i>
<br>

<i>И еще больше шрифта </i>
<br>
<br>

<input type="button" id="bt" value="Заменить">
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Код помог. Пробовала ранее этот метод, но не подставила return $("<strong>", {html: $(this).html()}), поэтому ничего не получалось.

Comment: @Elena примите, пожалуйста, ответ, если он вам помог

Comment: Спасибо, ответ давно принят. Если нужно дополнительно как-то это подтвердить - напишите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Elena как же он принят, если вы не отметили его как решение проблемы. Рядом слева с вопросом этим есть серая галочка - нажмите на ней. Так отмечают, что вопрос решёл, а этот ответ - решение. И автору ответа говорят так спасибо.

Comment: Вот тут должна быть галочка серая - https://i.imgur.com/rzUSkQw.png

Answer (score -1):

нужно использовать $('i').remove

почитайте документацию для корректной настройки работы: 
http://api.jquery.com/remove/ 
или как вариант ещё такой 
http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: remove удаляет элемент вместе с содержимым. removeAttr удаляет атрибут элемента.